# Trouble connecting to MySQL within Docker container after server restart

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a DigitalOcean droplet configured with Docker to host a MrSQL database. I am using an open source equivalent to Heroku to manage my containers called [Caprover](https://caprover.com/). This has worked excellent for me for months, but I realized that my MySQL database went down due to insufficient memory for InnoDB because my Docker instances were slowly taking up more memory over time. While debugging, I restarted my DigitalOcean droplet using `sudo shutdown -r now`. After restart (which normally fixes things), my db container logs displayed:

```
[Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.28' socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

So at least on the container side it is ready for connections. I hopped back over to Sequel Pro to log back in and I get an immediate connection error:

`Unable to connect to host MY_DIGITALOCEAN_IP, or the request timed out.`

I have always used the following configuration to log in:

```
Host: MY_DIGITAL_OCEAN_IP
username: root
password: MY_PASSWORD
Port: 4444
```

In my container configuration, I have mapped the internal port 3306 to 4444 as seen on my dashboard here:

[image]

What are the next steps I need to take to try and debug what is causing this sudden loss of MySQL connection?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, a second server restart fixed things...not sure why

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while running mysql in docker. Few things to take into consideration:

```
1. Increase the memory allocation of docker. 
   You can do it easily using docker desktop dashboard.
2. Run the docker-compose with an admin access.
       For an example: sudo docker-compose -f mysql.docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Point 2 above will resolve ***inaccessible file*** issue.

The above I have done it in my MacBook pro 11.5.1